# Importing MomentModule but told pipe not found

Tags: angular, momentjs

I'm trying Angular 2 and running into an issue; not sure if it's an issue with my understanding of pipes, structure, or bug, and could use advice.

I'm using [Moment for Angular 2](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) and am stuck. I've followed the instructions, installing angular-moment via NPM and importing MomentModule into my root module, included in my imports array. Without any pipes, my code runs as normal (I'm using Angular CLI, so I'm guessing it's doing tree shaking?). When I try using a pipe from the package, I get a console error that the pipe I'm using can't be found. I looked in the code to confirm I was typing it in correctly, but with no avail.

I can't tell where the issue is, me, Angular, the Moment Module, or something else, and could use advice on how to debug this in general.

My app.module.ts (which is my root) as requested:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FilterMenuComponent } from './filter-menu/filter-menu.component';

import { EventsListModule } from './events-list/events-list.module';

import { EventService } from './event.service';

    @NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        EventsListModule,
        MomentModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FilterMenuComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        EventService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The template being used is this (the template is for a component that is imported in the EventsListModule, which is imported into the root module):

```
<div (click)="toggleShowEntry()" class="title" [ngClass]="{ 'full': event.full, 'special': event.special }">
    {{event.key}}: <span [innerHtml]="event.title"></span> ({{event.date.start | amDateFormat:'dddd'}}, {{event.date.start.format('h:mm A')}} - {{event.date.end.format('h:mm A')}})
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your main module (@NgModule)

Comment: You need to post more info before people can help you out. Go into your project folder `project_folder/src/app` then find `app.module.ts` and post the code from that file

Comment: Added my root module as requested.

Comment: Can you post the template you're trying to use the pipe in.

Comment: Added the template.

Comment: If you haven't imported moment module into your event module then that most likely is the issue

Comment: So this is the confusion: I thought that if something is imported into the root module, you don't need to import it into child modules? For example, I imported `HttpModule` here but not in the EventListModule, but I can use it in the EventListModule with no problem?

Comment: Anyone resolved this issue as yet. MomentModule forces you to import it into any Feature module that requires it. It work for a moment the instant I imported into the feature module and stopped relying on the shared module.